# Center error bars (geom_errorbar) in point plot with four varibles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to center the error bars with my points on a plot. I'm using ggplot2 and this is part of my script:

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.9)

plot <- ggplot(sub.sum,aes(x=Type, y=Capture_Rate, colour=Gender))
plot <- plot + geom_point(aes(shape=Season),position=pd,size=5)
plot <- plot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Capture_Rate-ci, ymax=Capture_Rate+ci),width=.2,position=pd)
plot <- plot + facet_wrap(~Species,scales="free_y",nrow=4,ncol=2)
plot <- plot + xlab("")+ ylab("Capture Rate (bats/mnh)")
plot <- plot + theme_bw() + scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
plot <- plot + expand_limits(y=0)
plot <- plot + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=20,vjust=-1))
plot <- plot + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=25,angle=90,vjust=2))
plot <- plot + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=16,face="bold",angle=20,vjust=0.5))
plot <- plot + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18))
plot <- plot + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=20),
                     legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position="bottom", 
                     legend.key = element_blank()) 
plot <- plot + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5),"cm"))
plot <- plot + theme(strip.text.x = element_text(face="italic",size=20))
plot <- plot + theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))
plot <- plot + geom_vline(xintercept=c(1.5,2.5,3.5),color="red", linetype="dotted",size=1)
plot
```

When I don't have the Season I can easily center the erro bars with the points. But after adding the code that says that shape correspond to Season, that is not possible anymore. Here is an example of the problem:

[Plot showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2vUy.png)

As you can see in the image the erros bars are overlapping each other and they are not center with the points. They are just center with the image. I know it's a problem with the positioning, but I don't know how to solve it. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `shape=Season` in the `ggplot(aes())` rather than in `geom_point(aes())`.

Comment: Your are genius. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!